# Does anybody have samples of using CoreImage CICategoryTransition filters in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, cifilter

Apple added a number of "Transition" Core Image filters in iOS 6 (in the category CICategoryTransition).

Does anybody know of a sample project that shows how to use them to actually generate a live transition between images?

The only way I've used CI filters in iOS so far is to pass in a source CIImage, set the various parameters, and then ask the filter for it's output CIImage.

In my experience this is fairly slow. The CICategoryTransition category of filters have a time property. The documentation on how you use it is **very** thin, but I assume you vary the time parameter from 0 (beginning of transition) to 1.0 (end of transition), and get back an image of the transition at the specified stage. However, I don't think this would be fast enough to generate the 30 FPS needed for a smooth animation.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ that the documentation "**is thin**". I got this all from the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-BAJGIDBF)

Transition filters require the following tasks:

1. Create Core Image images (CIImage objects) to use for the
   transition.
2. Set up and schedule a timer.
3. Create a CIContext object.
4. Create a CIFilter object for the filter to apply to the image.
5. On OS X, set the default values for the filter.
6. Set the filter parameters.
7. Set the source and the target images to process.
8. Calculate the time.
9. Apply the filter.
10. Draw the result.
11. Repeat steps 8–10 until the transition is complete.

Getting images and setting up a timer

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

NSTimer    *timer;
NSURL      *url;

thumbnailWidth  = 340.0;
thumbnailHeight = 240.0;

url   = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                pathForResource: @"boots" ofType: @"jpg"]];
[self setSourceImage: [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL: url]];

url   = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                pathForResource: @"skier" ofType: @"jpg"]];
[self setTargetImage: [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL: url]];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0/30.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(timerFired:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];

base = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: timer
                             forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: timer
                             forMode: NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
}
```

Setting up the transition filter

```
- (void)setupTransition {
CGFloat w = thumbnailWidth;
CGFloat h = thumbnailHeight;

CIVector *extent = [CIVector vectorWithX: 0  Y: 0  Z: w  W: h];

transition  = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CICopyMachineTransition"];
// Set defaults on OS X; not necessary on iOS.
[transition setDefaults];
[transition setValue: extent forKey: kCIInputExtentKey];
}
```

The drawRect: method for the copy machine transition effect

```
- (void)drawRect: (NSRect)rectangle {
CGRect  cg = CGRectMake(NSMinX(rectangle), NSMinY(rectangle),
                        NSWidth(rectangle), NSHeight(rectangle));

CGFloat t = 0.4 * ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - base);
if (context == nil) {
    context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:
                    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]
                                      options: nil];
}
if (transition == nil) {
    [self setupTransition];
}
[context drawImage: [self imageForTransition: t + 0.1]
            inRect: cg
          fromRect: cg];
}
```

Applying the transition filter

```
- (CIImage *)imageForTransition: (float)t {

// Remove the if-else construct if you don't want the transition to loop
if (fmodf(t, 2.0) < 1.0f) {
    [transition setValue: sourceImage  forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transition setValue: targetImage  forKey: kCIInputTargetImageKey];
} else {
    [transition setValue: targetImage  forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
    [transition setValue: sourceImage  forKey: kCIInputTargetImageKey];
}

[transition setValue: @( 0.5 * (1 - cos(fmodf(t, 1.0f) * M_PI)) )
              forKey: kCIInputTimeKey];

CIFilter  *crop = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CICrop"
                             keysAndValues:
               kCIInputImageKey, [transition valueForKey: kCIOutputImageKey],
               @"inputRectangle", [CIVector vectorWithX: 0  Y: 0
                                   Z: thumbnailWidth  W: thumbnailHeight],
               nil];
return [crop valueForKey: kCIOutputImageKey];
}
```

Using the timer to update the display

```
- (void)timerFired: (id)sender {
[self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

Setting source and target images

```
- (void)setSourceImage: (CIImage *)source {
sourceImage = source;
}

- (void)setTargetImage: (CIImage *)target {
targetImage = target;
}
```

I also suggest looking at the following project example [CITransitionSelectorSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CITransitionSelectorSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I've put together code that's fairly similar to the above. I was hoping for something more performant. The code above creates a new CIImage for each frame in the transition, which is slow. I've written code to process video and recognize faces in it, and for that, I was able to map CVPixelBuffers for incoming "raw" video and outgoing processed video to OpenGL textures such that they are actually using the same memory. The pixel buffers persist throughout the video processing, so new buffers don't need to be allocated for each frame. I'm hoping for something like that for CI transition filters

Comment: Ah, I'll keep looking into to this.